# Div layout going wrong

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a div in which I have a image on the left and text on its right. With less text it works fine but when I add more and more text it just destroys the whole layout!

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TjDZa/)

See in the fiddle that the first 2 rows just work fine but when I add some more text(row 3) the layout gets horibblified.

How can I solve this issue?

**CSS:**

```
.postWidget {
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.postWidget img {
    float: left;
}
.postWidget .job_title {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.postWidget .description {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.postWidget .description span {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.postWidget span a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.postWidget .user_desc {
    margin-left: 80px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
.postWidget .user_desc .name {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.postWidget .user_desc .name, .profession {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `<span>` tags for your text? You should use `<p>` instead, like this:

```
<div class="description">
  <p class="for"><b>For:</b> Lorizzle ipsizzle owned shizznit amizzle, consectetizzle adipiscing dope. Nullizzle check out this velizzle, i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle volutpizzle, suscipit quis, yo pizzle, arcu. Pellentesque bow wow wow tortizzle. Sed erizzle. Shiznit izzle dolor dapibizzle turpizzle stuff fizzle. Maurizzle shizzlin dizzle gangster et turpizzle. Fizzle dawg fo. Check it out stuff you son of a bizzle sizzle. In gizzle habitasse platea dictumst. Fizzle dapibizzle. Break it down fizzle phat, pretizzle mofo, mattizzle sizzle, gangsta vitae, for sure. Hizzle suscipit. Integizzle bling bling velit pimpin'.</p>
  <br/><p class="offer"><b>Offer:</b> Lorizzle ipsizzle owned shizznit amizzle, consectetizzle adipiscing dope. Nullizzle check out this velizzle, i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle volutpizzle, suscipit quis, yo pizzle, arcu. Pellentesque bow wow wow tortizzle. Sed erizzle. Shiznit izzle dolor dapibizzle turpizzle stuff fizzle. Maurizzle shizzlin dizzle gangster et turpizzle. Fizzle dawg fo. Check it out stuff you son of a bizzle sizzle. In gizzle habitasse platea dictumst. Fizzle dapibizzle. Break it down fizzle phat, pretizzle mofo, mattizzle sizzle, gangsta vitae, for sure. Hizzle suscipit. Integizzle bling bling velit pimpin'.</p>
```

I also added some css:

```
.description p {
  margin:0 0 0 50px
}
```

If you use `<p>` tags, you can control the margin space instead of using `<br />` everywhere! Also, I think `<b>` tags might be deprecated (they're old!) use `<strong>` tags instead!

```
<div class="description">
  <p class="for"><strong>For:</strong> Lorizzle ipsizzle owned shizznit amizzle, consectetizzle adipiscing dope. Nullizzle check out this velizzle, i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle volutpizzle, suscipit quis, yo pizzle, arcu. Pellentesque bow wow wow tortizzle. Sed erizzle. Shiznit izzle dolor dapibizzle turpizzle stuff fizzle. Maurizzle shizzlin dizzle gangster et turpizzle. Fizzle dawg fo. Check it out stuff you son of a bizzle sizzle. In gizzle habitasse platea dictumst. Fizzle dapibizzle. Break it down fizzle phat, pretizzle mofo, mattizzle sizzle, gangsta vitae, for sure. Hizzle suscipit. Integizzle bling bling velit pimpin'.</p>
  <br/><p class="offer"><strong>Offer:</strong> Lorizzle ipsizzle owned shizznit amizzle, consectetizzle adipiscing dope. Nullizzle check out this velizzle, i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle volutpizzle, suscipit quis, yo pizzle, arcu. Pellentesque bow wow wow tortizzle. Sed erizzle. Shiznit izzle dolor dapibizzle turpizzle stuff fizzle. Maurizzle shizzlin dizzle gangster et turpizzle. Fizzle dawg fo. Check it out stuff you son of a bizzle sizzle. In gizzle habitasse platea dictumst. Fizzle dapibizzle. Break it down fizzle phat, pretizzle mofo, mattizzle sizzle, gangsta vitae, for sure. Hizzle suscipit. Integizzle bling bling velit pimpin'.</p>
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/Aknc8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

play with layout :)  http://jsfiddle.net/TjDZa/3/

```
.postWidget .description {
    margin-left: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can even set `margin-right` from `img` instead  `margin-left` from `.description` : http://jsfiddle.net/TjDZa/4/

```
.postWidget img {
    float: left;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.postWidget .description span {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```